# XSD: Single optional element in sequence

Tags: xml, xsd

I have XML files of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<hw:config name="test" xmlns:hw="hw">
  <switch var="var.test" >
    <case value="a">
    </case>
    <case value="b">
    </case>
    <default>
    </default>
    <case value="c">
    </case>
  </switch>
</hw:config>
```

I want an XSD that allows that there may be one default block or not, but not more than one. It may appear at any position between the case blocks.

The following XSD should do the job, but xmllint (libxml2) says 'The content model is not determinist.':

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:hw="hw" targetNamespace="hw" >

    <xsd:simpleType name="defaultType">
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="caseType">
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType >

    <xsd:complexType name="switchType" >
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="case" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="hw:caseType" />
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xsd:element name="default" type="hw:defaultType" />
          <xsd:element name="case" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="hw:caseType" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="var" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="configType" >
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="switch" type="hw:switchType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="config" type="hw:configType" />

</xsd:schema>
```

Why is this Schema not-determinist? Is there any way to rephrase this so that it becomes determinist?

Comment: This part seems OK to me. Are you sure the problem is caused by these lines? Could you show the whole schema?

Comment: I replaced the snippets with the whole file content. That's the way libxml version 20706 rejects it.

Comment: Now JAXP accepts the XSD. It might be a problem with libxml.

Comment: Oxygen 13.2 and the w3c online validation service detect no problems as well. I think it's safe to assume the schema is valid.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this appears to be a bug in xmllint (or rather libxml).  The equivalent DTD does not have any issues -- that is, the declaration

```
<!ELEMENT switch (case*, (default, case*)?) >
```

is accepted without complaint.  So it appears that the bug is purely in the XSD support, not in determinism checking more generally.

One workaround is to replace the (...)? with a choice between (default, case*) and the empty sequence:

```
<xsd:complexType name="switchType" >
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="case" 
                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                 type="hw:caseType" />
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:sequence/>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="default" type="hw:defaultType" />
        <xsd:element name="case" 
                     minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                     type="hw:caseType" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="var" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```